# invalid procedure call or argument excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, userform

i want have an add command and a search command. i thought if i reciprocate the add command then i can use it as a search command but it gives an invalid procedure call or argument.

add command:

```
Sub TransferMasterValue()
Dim allchecks As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
 'Iterate through the checkboxes concatenating a string of all names
   For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
     If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
       If ctrl Then
        allchecks = allchecks & ctrl.Name & " "
       End If
     End If
    Next

'If you have at least one transfer to the Master sheet
If Len(allchecks) > 0 Then
  Set ws1 = Sheets("Master")
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

     With ws1
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = surname.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = firstname.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = tod.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = program.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = email.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = officenumber.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = cellnumber.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = Left(allchecks, Len(allchecks) - 1)
     End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Search Command:

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim ctrl As control
Dim allchecks As String

  For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
      If ctrl.value = true Then
        allchecks = allchecks & ctrl.Name & " "


       End If
     End If
  Next

 Name = surname.Value

 With ws
   Set f = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
      With Me
        firstname.Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
        tod.Value = f.Offset(0, 2).Value
        program.Value = f.Offset(0, 3).Value
        email.Value = f.Offset(0, 4).Text
        officenumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 6).Text
        cellnumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 7).Text
```

EDIT:

```
If Len(allchekcs)>0 then
 If f.Offset(0, 5).Value = Left(allchecks, Len(allchecks) - 1) Then ctrl.Value = True
end if
```

EDIT: so i've added the if Len(allchecks)>0 then command, and it doesn't give error 5 but it still doesn't checkmark the userform checkboxes - how can i fix this? right now when the information is added to column 6, it's added as "Montreal Ottawa Toronto Vancouver" and perhaps that's why it's not picking it up? because there's multiple checkbox names in one cell? in order for ctrl.value = true to work the cell value has to equal to one ctrl.name? is there a way i can separate so it picks up using ctrl?

Comment: What is the value of allchecks when this error occurs (I guess it is `""`)? The second argument of `Left()` has to be greater than or equal 0. If you have "allchecks" as zero length value, then it will error out '5'.

Comment: @PatricK I've edited and added If Len(allchecks)>0 function but it's not picking up the ctrl.value = true. I've edited the post

Comment: So `allchecks` is `""`. The issue is at `If ctrl Then`. Can you try replace it with `If ctrl.Value = True Then`?

Comment: i've added the if ctrl.value = true then but nothing happens..

Comment: Most likely the variable `allchecks` is the root cause. Why do you append control names if it's checked, and then compare the whole string later? Don't get what is supposed to be in `f.Offset(0, 5)`. Are you trying to change the checkbox values based on the worksheet? I guess this is what you need: `ctrl.Value = (Instr(1,f.Offset(0, 5).Value,allchecks,vbTextCompare) = 1)`

Comment: 'f.offset(0,5)' is the names of the checkboxes - so when the user clicks on the checkbox from userform and click add the names of the checked checkboxes are transferred to column 6 (which is f.offset(0,5). and i'm trying to make a code that when i search i want the code to pick up whatever is written in column 6 and display it in the userform checkboxes. so if in column 6 (f.offset(0,5) there's Montreal Ottawa Vancouver then when i search by surname and click search the Montreal Ottawa Vancouver checkboxes would be checked in the userform.

Comment: I get an error 91 using the code above - how should i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To separate the values in the cell, use the `Split` command:

```
For each ctrl in UserForm1.Controls
    For i = 0 to UBound(Split(CellValue," "))
        If Split(CellValue, " ")(i) = ctrl.Name Then ctrl.Value = True
    Next i
Next
```

Where `CellValue` is the Value of the cell that contains the `allchecks` value.